# Find a CFG for a language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

In an assignment I've been asked to find a CFG for $a^x b^y a^z b^w$, where, $x,y,z,w \in \mathbb{N}^+$, $y > x$, $z > w$, and $x+z = y+w$. A hint was given, think of the language as $(a^p b^p)(b^q a^q)(a^r b^r)$.

I've had a go at it, and have come up with

- S -> A
- A -> aAbB | ab
- B -> bBaC | ba
- C -> aCb | ab

This language will give me equal $a$'s and $b$'s. The reason I've chained the productions together is that since $x,y,z,w$ can't be 0, when one production is done, the others must be done as well (that was my thinking). However, I can't help but be worried about order. Even the smallest production won't come out as in the order "abab". Is it possible to construct a CFG that imposes order and memory? Or do I have to go to a PDA then CFG? Or is it irrelevant?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint is another way of describing the same language. For the two languages to be the same, one must have: $x=p$, $y=p+q$, $z=q+r$, and $w=r$. Notice that these do satisfy the constraints $y\gt x, z\gt w$ and $x+z=y+w$ provided that $q,r\gt 0$. Now the structure of the hint language makes it easy to write a grammar.

$S \to ABA$

$A \to aAb|ab$

$B \to bBa|ba$

Comment: so $r$ should equals to $p$?

Comment: think of PDA, you push all '$a$'s to compare with number of '$b$'s you pop '$a$', Now have lost prefix sub-string $a^xb^y$ in PDS (I don't think hint is correct).

Comment: @Grijesh $r$ and $p$ are independent of each other. The only requirement is that both are greater than 0. (Otherwise $x$ resp. $w$ wouldn't be)

Comment: @FrankW May be I am wrong, I request you please read first statement in question. I don't think language is CFL (also i think hint given in question is wrong, that the reason I commented you). Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Grijesh I reread it after seeing your comments. I am absolutely sure that the hint from the question is correct and the language is CFL.

Comment: @FrankW Ok I got it I misunderstood. I was confused $x+z=y+w$ -- I though it is $x+y=z+w$ :P thanks!

Comment: Yes, the hint did make me realise it's the language that has equal a's and b's, I rewrote it to a^p b^p+q a^q+r b^r, I just couldn't think of how to do a^p b^p+q as a CFG. My initial answer got it to do almost what you did, @saadtaame, but it was really ugly-looking. I also got mislead by the a^r b^r - I made it C, instead of realising it's another A.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you mean by "chained the productions together" or "imposes order and memory" in your final paragraph.

However, the grammar you give does not work: If you apply the first rule for $A$ multiple times, you will end up with $aa\ldots aaAbBbB\ldots bBbB$ and each $B$ will yield at least one $a$, thus resulting in a word with too many switches from $a$ to $b$ and back.

What you can do is start with $S \rightarrow ABC$ and then have rules that generate the 3 subwords given in the hint from $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Comment: Do you think the hint is useful??

Comment: @Grijesh Obviously I do.

Comment: Which hint you think useful one in question, or one in your answer?

Comment: your as well as @saadtaame is also correct thanks.

Comment: What I meant by chaining was forcing A to generate a B and forcing B to generate a C, my vocab is pretty poor in that department.

With regards to order and memory, if I converted this to a PDA, I'd be able to use the stack to remember x,y,z,w so I could accept words in the order abab. But with a CFG, I can't figure out how I'd force the productions to come out a^x b^y a^z b^w (abab). I don't know if that's clearer.

Comment: With your S -> ABC suggestion, I thought that's what I was doing, I was just staggering the productions, however I do see the error of my ways, thanks.

Comment: @Sethmo I think, I roughly get it now. I don't think checking the conditions on $x, y, z, w$ directly is possible with a PDA or CFG, since there are multiple conditions that would use the stack in incompatible ways, if checked directly.